# A couple of url paths not working anymore after creating class ProfileDetailView

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-views, django-urls

I am working on a social website and after creating a class to render the user's profile in detail. The path that render all posts and all profiles aren't working anymore and I get the same error and when I uncomment the code from line 21 to 24 (def get_object) function it says "Does Not Exist at /posts/"

> Profile matching query does not exist.
>
> Page not found (404)
>
> No profile found matching the query
>
> Request Method:   GET
> Request URL:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/posts/
> Raised by:    network.views.<class 'network.views.ProfileDetailView'>

Using the URLconf defined in project4.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

```
admin/
[name='index']
login [name='login']
logout [name='logout']
register [name='register']
<slug>/ [name='profile-view']
```

The current path, posts/, matched the last one.
"
Urls:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path("", views.index, name="index"),
    path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
    path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
    path("register", views.register, name="register"),
    path("<slug>/", ProfileDetailView.as_view(), name="profile-view"),
    path("posts/", post_comment_create_view, name="posts"),
    path("liked/", like_unlike_post, name="like-post-view"),
    path("<pk>/delete", PostDeleteView.as_view(), name="post-delete"),
    path("<pk>/update", PostUpdateView.as_view(), name="post-update"),
    path("invites/", invites_received_view, name="invites-view"),
    path("allprofiles/", ProfileListView.as_view(), name="all-profiles-view"),
    path("send-invite/", send_invitation, name="send-invite"),
    path("remove-friend/", remove_friends, name="remove-friend"),
    path("invites/accept/", accept_invitation, name="accept-invite"),
    path("invites/reject/", reject_invitation, name="reject-invite"),

]
```

Views:

```
from .models import Relationship, Post, Profile, Like
from django.views.generic import TemplateView, View, UpdateView, DeleteView, ListView, DetailView
from .forms import ProfileModelForm, PostModelForm, CommentModelForm

class ProfileDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile.html'

     def get_object(self, slug=None):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')
       profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)
         return profile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)
        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["posts"] = self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()
        context["len_posts"] = True if len(self.get_object().get_all_authors_posts()) > 0 else False


        return context


class MyProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'network/my_profile.html'


def index(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    context = {
        'hello': 'hello world!',
        'qs':qs,
    }
    return render(request, "network/index.html", context)

def profile_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    form = ProfileModelForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None, instance=profile)
    confirm = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            confirm = True

    context = {
        'profile': profile,
        'form': form,
        'confirm': confirm,
    }
    return render(request, 'network/profile.html', context)

def invites_received_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    qs = Relationship.objects.invitations_received(profile)
    results = list(map(lambda x: x.sender, qs))
    is_empty = False
    if len(results) == 0:
        is_empty = True

    context = {
        'qs':results,
        'is_empty': is_empty,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/invites.html', context)

def accept_invitation(request):
    if request.method =='POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        sender = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        rel = get_object_or_404(Relationship, sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
        if rel.status == 'send':
            rel.status = 'accepted'
            rel.save()

    return redirect('invites-view')

def reject_invitation(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
        sender = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)
        rel = get_object_or_404(Relationship, sender=sender, receiver=receiver)
        rel.delete()
    return redirect('invites-view')


def invite_profiles_list_view(request):
    user = request.user
    qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles_to_invite(user)

    context = {'qs': qs}

    return render(request, 'network/to_invite_list.html', context)

def profiles_list_view(request):
    user = request.user
    qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(user)

    context = {'qs': qs}

    return render(request, 'network/profile_list.html', context)

class ProfileListView(ListView):
    model = Profile
    template_name = 'network/profile_list.html'
    context_object_name = 'qs'

    def get_queryset(self):
        qs = Profile.objects.get_all_profiles(self.request.user)
        return qs

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = User.objects.get(username__iexact=self.request.user)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        rel_r = Relationship.objects.filter(sender=profile)
        rel_s = Relationship.objects.filter(receiver=profile)
        rel_receiver = []
        rel_sender = []
        for item in rel_r:
            rel_receiver.append(item.receiver.user)
        for item in rel_s:
            rel_sender.append(item.sender.user)
        context["rel_receiver"] = rel_receiver
        context["rel_sender"] = rel_sender
        context["is_empty"] = False
        if len(self.get_queryset()) == 0:
            context["is_empty"] = True

        return context

def send_invitation(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        user = request.user
        sender = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)

        rel = Relationship.objects.create(sender=sender, receiver=receiver, status='send')

        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return redirect('profile')


def remove_friends(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('profile_pk')
        user = request.user
        sender = Profile.objects.get(user=user)
        receiver = Profile.objects.get(pk=pk)

        rel = Relationship.objects.get(
            (Q(sender=sender) & Q(receiver=receiver)) | (Q(sender=receiver) & Q(receiver=sender))
        )
        rel.delete()
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
    return redirect('profile')

def like_unlike_post(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        post_id = request.POST.get('post_id')
        post_obj = Post.objects.get(id=post_id)
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=user)

        if profile in post_obj.liked.all():
            post_obj.liked.remove(profile)
        else:
            post_obj.liked.add(profile)

        like, created = Like.objects.get_or_create(user=profile, post_id=post_id)

        if not created:
            if like.value=='Like':
                like.value='Unlike'
            else:
                like.value='Like'
        else:
            like.value='Unlike'

            post_obj.save()
            like.save()

    return redirect('posts')


def post_view_json(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    data = serializers.serialize('json', qs)
    return JsonResponse({'data': data})

def profile_test_view(request):
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    return render(request, "network/profile_test.html", {'profile':profile})

def post_comment_create_view(request):
    qs = Post.objects.all()
    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    #Setting up pagination
    p = Paginator(qs, 5)
    page = request.GET.get('page')
    post_list = p.get_page(page)

    #Post form, comment form
    p_form = PostModelForm()
    c_form = CommentModelForm()
    post_added = False

    profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)

    if 'submit_pForm' in request.POST:
        print(request.POST)
        p_form = PostModelForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if p_form.is_valid():
            instance = p_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.author = profile
            instance.save()
            p_form = PostModelForm()
            post_added = True

    if 'submit_cForm' in request.POST:
        c_form = CommentModelForm(request.POST)
        if c_form.is_valid():
            instance = c_form.save(commit=False)
            instance.user = profile
            instance.post = Post.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('post_id'))
            instance.save()
            c_form = CommentModelForm()

    context = {
        'qs': qs,
        'profile': profile,
        'p_form': p_form,
        'c_form': c_form,
        'post_added': post_added,
        'post_list': post_list,
    }

    return render(request, 'network/posts.html', context)

class PostDeleteView(DeleteView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'network/confirmDelete.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        obj = Post.objects.get(pk=pk)
        if not obj.author.user == self.request.user:
            messages.warning(self.request, 'You need to be the owner of the post in order to delete it!')
        return obj

class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    form_class = PostModelForm
    model = Post
    template_name = 'network/update.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('posts')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        if form.instance.author == profile:
            return super().form_valid(form)
        else:
            form.add_error(None, "You need to be the owner of the post in order to update it!")
            return super().form_invalid(form)
```

Comment: Looks like you need to define a view which will serve your url *posts/*, *views.view_name*.

Comment: It exists "post_comment_create_view" @MathewO'Sullivan, and it was working right before creating ProfileDetailView class

Comment: Should you add **views** before view name?

Comment: Diddn't work, error highlights this line "profile = Profile.objects.get(slug=slug)" @MathewO'Sullivan

Comment: Please provide the Post Model and also remove the code from above which has no issue so we can focus only on the code which has issues.

Comment: is ProfileDetailView working?